# My custom header does not change the header image height and width

Tags: custom-header

Here is my code in functions.php

```
$custom_header_args=array(
    'default-image'          => '',
    'width'                  => 500,
    'height'                 => 500,
    'flex-height'            => true,
    'flex-width'             => true,
    'uploads'                => true,
    'random-default'         => false,
    'header-text'            => true,
    'default-text-color'     => '',
    'wp-head-callback'       => '',
    'admin-head-callback'    => '',
    'admin-preview-callback' => '',
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-header' ,$custom_header_args);
```

And here is my code in header.php

```
<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" height="<?php get_custom_header()->height ?>" width="<?php get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="">
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location'  => 'primary') ); ?>
```

My question is it does not change the height and width of my header
image. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> You have forgot to do "echo" the Height & Width in Image code. Your Header code should like below.

```
<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="">
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location'  => 'primary') ); ?>
```

> check this reference https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers

Comment: even though I put an echo it does not change the height and width when it display in the website...I use vardump to check the size and here is the result ...  ["width"]=> int(402) ["height"]=> int(125) ["video"]=> bool(false) ["attachment_id"]=> int(79) } it remains the size from where I upload the image..